# Как сделать такое переключение на radiobutton?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, есть такой код:

```js
var label = document.querySelectorAll('.item-inner label[data-target]'),
  labelInner = document.querySelectorAll('.form-two label[data-target]'),
  itemDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.box-style'),
  itemDivInner = document.querySelectorAll('.box'),
  buttonPay = document.getElementById('payment_button'),
  form = document.querySelector('.invoice'),
  buttonForm = document.querySelector('.link-form');

function checkLabel(element, className) {
  className.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove('active');
  });

  var targetDiv = document.querySelector(element.getAttribute('data-target'));

  targetDiv.classList.add('active');
}

label.forEach(function(checked) {
  checked.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    checkLabel(this, itemDiv);
    form.classList.add('show');
    if (checked.getAttribute('for') === 'sub2') {
      buttonPay.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      buttonPay.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
  });
});

labelInner.forEach(function(checked) {
  checked.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    checkLabel(this, itemDivInner);
  });
});

buttonForm.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  labelInner.forEach(function(checked) {
    if (checked.getAttribute('for') == 'sub6') {
      checked.previousElementSibling.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
      checkLabel(checked, itemDivInner);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* ---------------------------------------------
    Assets
--------------------------------------------- */

/* ---------------------------------------------
    Colors
--------------------------------------------- */

/* ---------------------------------------------
    Fonts
--------------------------------------------- */

/* ---------------------------------------------
    Stylings
--------------------------------------------- */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*display: -webkit-box;*/
  /*display: -moz-box;*/
  /*display: box;*/
  /*display: -webkit-flex;*/
  /*display: -moz-flex;*/
  /*display: -ms-flexbox;*/
  /*display: flex;*/
  /*-webkit-box-pack: center;*/
  /*-moz-box-pack: center;*/
  /*box-pack: center;*/
  /*-webkit-justify-content: center;*/
  /*-moz-justify-content: center;*/
  /*-ms-justify-content: center;*/
  /*-o-justify-content: center;*/
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  /*-ms-flex-pack: center;*/
  /*-webkit-box-align: start;*/
  /*-moz-box-align: start;*/
  /*box-align: start;*/
  /*-webkit-align-items: flex-start;*/
  /*-moz-align-items: flex-start;*/
  /*-ms-align-items: flex-start;*/
  /*-o-align-items: flex-start;*/
  /*align-items: flex-start;*/
  /*-ms-flex-align: start;*/
  background-color: #CCCC33;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: #3f51b5;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.body-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
/*@media (min-height: 580px) {*/

/*!*body {*!*/

/*!*-webkit-box-align: center;*!*/

/*!*-moz-box-align: center;*!*/

/*!*box-align: center;*!*/

/*!*-webkit-align-items: center;*!*/

/*!*-moz-align-items: center;*!*/

/*!*-ms-align-items: center;*!*/

/*!*-o-align-items: center;*!*/

/*!*align-items: center;*!*/

/*!*-ms-flex-align: center;*!*/

/*!*}*!*/

/*}*/

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 580px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
.invoice {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 50px 30px 30px;
}
.invoice header {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.invoice header section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 120px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) h1 {
  /* float: left; */
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #344760;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) span {
  float: right;
  color: #b7bcc3;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) .logo img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: -35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  content: "";
  height: 140px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) {
  float: right;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span {
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #b7bcc3;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span:before {
  content: "#";
}
.invoice main {
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.invoice footer {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.invoice footer button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.invoice footer button:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
  background-color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled {
  color: #b7bcc3;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:hover:after {
  display: none;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:after {
  background-color: #b7bcc3;
}
.iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #344760;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
.inner input[type=text] {
  border: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  outline: none;
  color: #344760;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
  transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
}
.inner input[type=text]:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.inner input[type=text]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #CCCC33;
}
.inner textarea {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #344760;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
  transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 5px;
  min-height: 130px;
}
.inner textarea:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  text-align: center;
}
.form-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form-item .rub {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.form-item label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #344760;
}
.rub {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #344760;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.input-sum {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 56px;
  width: 110px;
}
.item label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: left;
}
.item label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCC33;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}
.item input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #CCCC33;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
.box-style {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: none;
}
.box {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: none;
}
.box-style p {
  line-height: 21px;
}
.box-style .col-item {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-right: -4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
.invoice.show footer button {
  margin-top: -51px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="invoice">
      <header>
        <section>
          <h1 class="invoice-title">Тип</h1>
        </section>
      </header>
      <main>
        <section class="inner">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item">
              <input id="sub1" name="form" type="radio" value="">
              <label for="sub1" data-target=".form-one"><span>Оплата</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <input id="sub2" name="form" type="radio">
              <label for="sub2" data-target=".form-two"><span>Оплата Другая</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-style form-one">
            <div class="form-item">
              <label for="sub3">ФИО</label>
              <input type="text" id="sub3" placeholder="Иванов Иван Иванович">
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
              <span class="input-sum">
      <label for="sub4">Сумма</label>
      <input type="text" id="sub4">
     </span>
              <span class="rub">&#8381;</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-style form-two">
            <h2>выберите способ</h2>
            <div class="item">
              <input id="sub5" name="form1" type="radio" value="">
              <label for="sub5" data-target=".form-three"><span>Карта</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <input id="sub6" name="form1" type="radio">
              <label for="sub6" data-target=".form-four"><span>Онлайн</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="box form-three">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam amet unde aperiam, rerum ab ipsa, dolore vitae dolor assumenda incidunt perferendis in recusandae officia necessitatibus nam soluta quas reiciendis ea.</p>
              <p class="italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis error natus, voluptatem consequatur, rem, neque consectetur eligendi id, ipsa aut eius illo quasi voluptates placeat reprehenderit praesentium. Iure, eum, repudiandae.
                <a href="#" class="link-form">форму</a>.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box form-four">
              Здесь есть форма
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>

      <footer>
        <button type="submit" id="payment_button" disabled="">Оплатить</button>
      </footer>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Не могу реализовать следующие. Открыв *radiobutton 'Оплата другая'* и дальше открыв кнопку *'Карта'* там можно увидеть ссылку *'форму'*, кликая по ней должен открываться и становится активным соседний *radiobutton 'Онлайн'*. Я тут попробовал это реализовать, но не совсем то получилось. что надо, то есть тут при первом клике все отрабатывает нормально, соседний *radiobutton* становится активным и показывает что надо, но если переключится на другую вкладку и кликнуть опять то кнопка *'Онлайн'* не становится активной. Можете подсказать пожалуйста. как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Зачем вы всё так усложнили? Вы могли эти же функции без скриптов сделать

Comment: <a href="#" class="link-form" onclick="document.getElementById('sub6').click()">форму</a> - способ костыльный, но проблему решает

Comment: Я изменил свой ответ добавив вариант с вашим скриптом. Смотрите

Comment: @Yuri спасибо в который раз за помощь!)

Answer (score 0):

Установленный вами атрибут *checked* ещё не означает, что input'y будет установлен флажок. Для таких целей используйте стандартную функцию `elem.checked = true`:

```js
var label = document.querySelectorAll('.item-inner label[data-target]'),
  labelInner = document.querySelectorAll('.form-two label[data-target]'),
  itemDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.box-style'),
  itemDivInner = document.querySelectorAll('.box'),
  buttonPay = document.getElementById('payment_button'),
  form = document.querySelector('.invoice'),
  buttonForm = document.querySelector('.link-form');

function checkLabel(element, className) {
  className.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove('active');
  });

  var targetDiv = document.querySelector(element.getAttribute('data-target'));

  targetDiv.classList.add('active');
}

label.forEach(function(checked) {
  checked.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    checkLabel(this, itemDiv);
    form.classList.add('show');
    if (checked.getAttribute('for') === 'sub2') {
      buttonPay.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      buttonPay.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
  });
});

labelInner.forEach(function(checked) {
  checked.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    checkLabel(this, itemDivInner);
  });
});

buttonForm.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  labelInner.forEach(function(checked) {
    if(checked.getAttribute('for') == 'sub6') {
      checked.previousElementSibling.checked = true;
      checkLabel(checked, itemDivInner);
    };
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CCCC33;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: #3f51b5;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.body-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 580px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
.invoice {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 50px 30px 30px;
}
.invoice header {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.invoice header section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 120px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) h1 {
  /* float: left; */
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #344760;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) span {
  float: right;
  color: #b7bcc3;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) .logo img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: -35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  content: "";
  height: 140px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) {
  float: right;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span {
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #b7bcc3;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span:before {
  content: "#";
}
.invoice main {
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.invoice footer {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.invoice footer button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.invoice footer button:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
  background-color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled {
  color: #b7bcc3;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:hover:after {
  display: none;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:after {
  background-color: #b7bcc3;
}
.iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #344760;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
.inner input[type=text] {
  border: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  outline: none;
  color: #344760;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
  transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
}
.inner input[type=text]:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.inner input[type=text]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #CCCC33;
}
.inner textarea {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #344760;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
  transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 5px;
  min-height: 130px;
}
.inner textarea:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  text-align: center;
}
.form-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form-item .rub {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.form-item label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #344760;
}
.rub {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #344760;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.input-sum {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 56px;
  width: 110px;
}
.item label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: left;
}
.item label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCC33;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}
.item input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #CCCC33;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
.box-style {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: none;
}
.box {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: none;
}
.box-style p {
  line-height: 21px;
}
.box-style .col-item {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-right: -4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
.invoice.show footer button {
  margin-top: -51px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="invoice">
      <header>
        <section>
          <h1 class="invoice-title">Тип</h1>
        </section>
      </header>
      <main>
        <section class="inner">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item">
              <input id="sub1" name="form" type="radio" value="">
              <label for="sub1" data-target=".form-one"><span>Оплата</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <input id="sub2" name="form" type="radio">
              <label for="sub2" data-target=".form-two"><span>Оплата Другая</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-style form-one">
            <div class="form-item">
              <label for="sub3">ФИО</label>
              <input type="text" id="sub3" placeholder="Иванов Иван Иванович">
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
              <span class="input-sum">
                <label for="sub4">Сумма</label>
                <input type="text" id="sub4">
              </span>
              <span class="rub">&#8381;</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-style form-two">
            <h2>выберите способ</h2>
            <div class="item">
              <input id="sub5" name="form1" type="radio" value="">
              <label for="sub5" data-target=".form-three"><span>Карта</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <input id="sub6" name="form1" type="radio">
              <label for="sub6" data-target=".form-four"><span>Онлайн</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="box form-three">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam amet unde aperiam, rerum ab ipsa, dolore vitae dolor assumenda incidunt perferendis in recusandae officia necessitatibus nam soluta quas reiciendis ea.</p>
              <p class="italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis error natus, voluptatem consequatur, rem, neque consectetur eligendi id, ipsa aut eius illo quasi voluptates placeat reprehenderit praesentium. Iure, eum, repudiandae.
                <a href="#" class="link-form">форму</a>.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box form-four">
              Здесь есть форма
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>

      <footer>
        <button type="submit" id="payment_button" disabled="">Оплатить</button>
      </footer>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Предлагаю ещё такой рабочий вариант, который не требует использования скриптов:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CCCC33;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: #3f51b5;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.body-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 580px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
.invoice {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 50px 30px 30px;
}
.invoice header {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.invoice header section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 120px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #344760;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) span {
  float: right;
  color: #b7bcc3;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) .logo img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: -35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  content: "";
  height: 140px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) {
  float: right;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span {
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #b7bcc3;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span:before {
  content: "#";
}
.invoice main {
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.invoice footer {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.invoice footer button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.invoice footer button:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
  background-color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled {
  color: #b7bcc3;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:hover:after {
  display: none;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:after {
  background-color: #b7bcc3;
}
.iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #344760;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
.inner input[type=text] {
  border: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  outline: none;
  color: #344760;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
  transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
}
.inner input[type=text]:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.inner input[type=text]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #CCCC33;
}
.inner textarea {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #344760;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
  transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 5px;
  min-height: 130px;
}
.inner textarea:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  text-align: center;
}
.form-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form-item .rub {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.form-item label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #344760;
}
.rub {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #344760;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.input-sum {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 56px;
  width: 110px;
}
.item label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: left;
}
.item label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCC33;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
.box-style {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: none;
}
.box {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: none;
}
.box-style p {
  line-height: 21px;
}
.box-style .link {
  color: #3f51b5;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box-style .link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.box-style .col-item {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-right: -4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.invoice.show footer button {
  margin-top: -51px;
}
.inner label:after {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #CCCC33;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  content: "";
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#sub1:checked ~ .form-one {
  display: block;
}
#sub1:checked ~ .item-inner .item label[for="sub1"] > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
#sub1:checked ~ .item-inner .item label[for="sub1"]:after {
  display: inline-block;
}
#sub2:checked ~ .form-two {
  display: block;
}
#sub2:checked ~ .item-inner .item label[for="sub2"] > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
#sub2:checked ~ .item-inner .item label[for="sub2"]:after {
  display: inline-block;
}
#sub5:checked ~ .form-two .form-three {
  display: block;
}
#sub5:checked ~ .form-two .item label[for="sub5"] > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
#sub5:checked ~ .form-two .item label[for="sub5"]:after {
  display: inline-block;
}
#sub6:checked ~ .form-two .form-four {
  display: block;
}
#sub6:checked ~ .form-two .item label[for="sub6"] > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
#sub6:checked ~ .form-two .item label[for="sub6"]:after {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="invoice">
      <header>
        <section>
          <h1 class="invoice-title">Тип</h1>
        </section>
      </header>
      <main>
        <section class="inner">
          <input id="sub1" name="form" type="radio" value="">
          <input id="sub2" name="form" type="radio">
          <input id="sub5" name="form1" type="radio" value="">
          <input id="sub6" name="form1" type="radio">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item">
              <label for="sub1"><span>Оплата</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <label for="sub2" data-target=".form-two"><span>Оплата Другая</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-style form-one">
            <div class="form-item">
              <label for="sub3">ФИО</label>
              <input type="text" id="sub3" placeholder="Иванов Иван Иванович">
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
              <span class="input-sum">
                <label for="sub4">Сумма</label>
                <input type="text" id="sub4">
              </span>
              <span class="rub">&#8381;</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-style form-two">
            <h2>выберите способ</h2>
            <div class="item">
              <label for="sub5"><span>Карта</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <label for="sub6"><span>Онлайн</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="box form-three">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam amet unde aperiam, rerum ab ipsa, dolore vitae dolor assumenda incidunt perferendis in recusandae officia necessitatibus nam soluta quas reiciendis ea.</p>
              <p class="italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis error natus, voluptatem consequatur, rem, neque consectetur eligendi id, ipsa aut eius illo quasi voluptates placeat reprehenderit praesentium. Iure, eum, repudiandae.
                <label for="sub6" class="link-form link">форму</label>.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box form-four">
              Здесь есть форма
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>

      <footer>
        <button type="submit" id="payment_button" disabled="">Оплатить</button>
      </footer>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо в который раз за помощь!)

Comment: @Lorax, не за что :)